# How to get the text field values in the Table view in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have created login page which contains the user name and password. I created one custom cell and it has one label and one text field. And i have created one grouped table view and used the custom cell. Actually i have created successfully but the problem is, how can i get the text field values for user name and pass word. Bcoz i have used only one textfield for both fields. I couldn't get the textfield values properly. I always get the last value for both fields. How can i get the user name and pass word text values properly?

Here my sample code,

In custom Cell,

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell {

    UILabel *userLbl;

    UITextField *userTxt;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *userLbl;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *userTxt;

@end
```

In Root View Controller,

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for(id currentObjects in nibObjects)
        {
            if([currentObjects isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]])
            {
                cell = (CustomCell *) currentObjects;
            }
        }
    }
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            [[cell userLbl] setText:@"User Name:"];

            cell.userTxt.tag = 0;

            //self.userName = [[cell userTxt] text];


        }
        if (indexPath.row == 1) {

            [[cell userLbl] setText:@"Pass Word:"];

            cell.userTxt.secureTextEntry = YES;

            //self.passWord = [[cell userTxt] text];

            cell.userTxt.tag = 1;

        }

    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


    // Configure the cell.

    return cell;
}

-(IBAction) submitAction : (id) sender
{

    self.userName = [[cell userTxt] text];

    self.passWord = [[cell userTxt] text];

    [cell.userTxt resignFirstResponder];

    NSLog(@"The user Name is %@", self.userName);

    NSLog(@"The password is %@", self.passWord);

     //Doesn't work

 /*   UITextField *txtField = (UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:0];

    self.userName = [txtField text];

    UITextField *txtField1 = (UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    self.passWord = [txtField1 text];

  NSLog(@"The user Name is %@",  self.userName);

  NSLog(@"The password is %@", self.passWord);*/

}
```

Here my screen shot of the image is,

[image]

PLease Help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the textFieldShouldEndEditing method if you are using more than one textfield as the textFieldShouldReturn method will only get the string from the textfield that resigns FirstResponder and thus you will miss all other textfields. This is what I used in my recent project when i had a form built with the tableview and textfields. It had me puzzled for a while.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    switch (textField.tag) 
    {
        case 0:
            userName = textField.text;
            break;

        case 1:
            passWord = textField.text;
            break;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use tag for each text field and the call -

```
UITextField *txtField = (UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:tag];
NSString *text = [txtField text];
```

and also 7KV7 is right you are assigning same tag to both text fields.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it elegantly? In your `UITextFieldDelegate` method, do it like this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
[textField resignFirstResponder];

   switch (textField.tag) {
    case 0:
        self.userName = textField.text;
        break;
    case 1:
        self.passWord = textField.text;
        break;   
    default:
        break;
 }
}
```

That way, you already have the data when the user clicks submit. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem in the way you set the tag for the textfields. I guess both have the same tags 1. Pls see if changing that helps

**UPDATE**

By the way how can you access the cell within the method `submitAction`. I think its easier to assign the text in `textfields` to an instance variable say `username` and `password` and use that in your method.

Comment: I can't get your updated answer, so please explain more abt that. Thanks.

Comment: By the way how can you access the cell within the method submitAction. I think its easier to assign the text in textfields to an instance variable say username and password and use that in your method.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. The problem is, i have created one textfield in the custom cell and its used in the table view for both user name and pass word fields. If i set the tag values, it couldn't set properly. -(IBAction) submitAction : (id) sender
{
  
   UITextField *txtField = (UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:0];
 
 NSString *text = [txtField text];
 
 UITextField *txtField1 = (UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
 
 NSString *text1 = [txtField1 text];
  
   NSLog(@"The user Name is %@",  text);
 
   NSLog(@"The password is %@", text1);
 
}

Comment: I dont think u can get `cell` within this method. Store the text in in ivar and use it in your method